# Get all rows from a table having a particular column value but ordered by different column value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am having trouble formulating this question, so I would give an example to demonstrate. Consider my table as,

```
CREATE TABLE ABC
(
    PID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    DISP_COL VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    VAL_COL VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    ORD_COL1 NUMBER(5,2),
    ORD_COL2 NUMBER(5,2),
    CONSTRAINT PK_PID PRIMARY KEY
    (
        PID
    )
);
```

And the data I have is,

```
PID | DISP_COL | VAL_COL | ORD_COL1 | ORD_COL2
----------------------------------------------
1   | DISP1    | VAL1    | 1        | 14
2   | DISP2    | VAL26   | 2        | 22
3   | DISP1    | VAL8    | 1        | 17
4   | DISP1    | VAL56   | 1        | 9
5   | DISP2    | VAL9    | 2        | -10
6   | DISP3    | VAL12   | 2        | 20
7   | AISP1    | VAL7    | 2        | -3
```

Now based on the descending ordering of ORD_COL1, ORD_COL2, I want to get the unique DISP_COL values and then all rows of that DISP_COL value to follow. So my data should like,

```
PID | DISP_COL | VAL_COL | ORD_COL1 | ORD_COL2
----------------------------------------------
2   | DISP2    | VAL26   | 2        | 22
5   | DISP2    | VAL9    | 2        | -10
6   | DISP3    | VAL12   | 2        | 20
7   | AISP1    | VAL7    | 2        | -3
3   | DISP1    | VAL8    | 1        | 17
1   | DISP1    | VAL1    | 1        | 14
4   | DISP1    | VAL56   | 1        | 9
```

A simple ORDER BY ORD_COL1 DESC, ORD_COL2 DESC does get me the order I want DISP_COL to occur but then I want the same valued rows to follow that.

I am kind of new to oracle and pl/sql, so all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what's wrong with `ORDER BY ORD_COL1 DESC, ORD_COL2 DESC` again? It will produce exactly same output as in your post.

Comment: I am sorry, I changed the table values now to reflect my question better. A simple `ORDER BY ORD_COL1 DESC, ORD_COL2 DESC` would put PID:5 below PID:6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query worked (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c340b/2/0)

```
SELECT A1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM ABC) A1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISP_COL, MAX(ORD_COL1) COL1, MAX(ORD_COL2) COL2 FROM ABC
 GROUP BY DISP_COL
 ORDER BY COL1 DESC, COL2 DESC) A2 ON (A1.DISP_COL = A2.DISP_COL)
ORDER BY A2.COL1 DESC, A2.COL2 DESC, A2.DISP_COL, A1.ORD_COL1 DESC,
A1.ORD_COL2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM ABC ORDER BY ORD_COL1 DESC, DISP_COL ASC, ORD_COL2 DESC;`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40401/18

You will need to order by the `DISP_COL` in `ASC` in order to get the result you want. See the updated fiddle and the code above. This will give you what you want from you question.

Comment: The SQL query I want, has to specifically bring that negative number up because it is a part of the DISP2 value which has the highest score on ORD_COL1 and ORD_COL2. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: Okay, see the updated answer above, I was able to get it to work with what you want.

Comment: It works in this scenario I guess but imagine a row of data in the same table as:
    `7 | AISP1 | VAL7 | 2 | -3`
Even though ORD_COL2 has a lower value than that of PID:2, it will still become the first row because `AISP` is alphabetically higher than `DISP`.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How many different variations can there be?

Comment: I apologize for making so many changes to the original data, still figuring out the best dataset I can give you to illustrate my question.
My aim here is to select the "DISTINCT" DISP_COL value which has the highest ORD_COL1, ORD_COL2 value. Once I select that value, I want to list out all the other rows with the same DISP_COL value but again within themselves ordered by ORD_COL1 and ORD_COL2. I was seeing if there is a way to do this without using a PL/SQL FOR LOOP

Comment: What is `DISP_COL` suppose to be? What kind of values will it hold? Is this what the data will actually be? The way you want to have the data, there isn't a straight forward way. It would required logic to order the records.